# Ignoring files having different extensions with .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I would like to ignore all files with extensions `*.mtx` or `*.otc` in a certain folder (`data/`) and all files with extension `*.pyc` in all subfolders. Will this `.gitignore` should work?

```
/data/*.mtx
/data/*.otc
*.pyc
```

Is there a way to make it more compact? Apparently this doesn't work:

```
/data/(*.mtx|*.otc)
*.pyc
```

Comment: why not use `git status` and see if it is working?

Comment: Assuming `data/` is at the top-level and your `.gitignore` is at the top-level, yes the first example should work.  The second one does not because `.gitignore` only accepts a basic glob-style syntax.  You can find more out about the syntax [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: `.gitignore` syntax uses glob wildcards, which do not have a way of doing what you are trying to do. So the answer is: No, not possible. You could save a few characters by putting a `.gitignore` with just `*.mtx` and `*.otc` into `/data/`.

Comment: @Sinapse good point, but I literally just learned about GitHub the last week, and about `git` even later than that. I'm not still familiar with all commands.

Comment: @jszakmeister all your assumptions are correct.

Comment: @poke good to know that what I'd like to do is not possible. I'd rather not use local `gitignore` unless strictly necessary, because it seems to me tidier to have all "ignore" instructions in one place, but I'm open to suggestions here. Anyway, if the only reason to have that local `.gitignore` is to save a few characters, I'll go with my original version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd rather not use local gitignore unless strictly necessary, because it seems to me tidier to have all "ignore" instructions in one place, but I'm open to suggestions here

You can keep only one .gitginore at the root folder of your repo.

```
**/data/*.mtx
**/data/*.otc
*.pyc
```

That would ignore `mtx` or `otc` files in data folders, even if data is not a top-level folder (because you are not using the anchor '/').

Check if this is working with:

```
git check-ignore -v path/to/a/file
```